# SQL Server calculation returning 0 instead of a float value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do the following operation in SQL to calculate the weighted rating :

```
SELECT CTE_3.idProduct,(CTE_3.vote_count / (CTE_3.vote_count + @minimumVotesRequired)) * CTE_3.vote_mean + (@minimumVotesRequired / (CTE_3.vote_count+ @minimumVotesRequired)) * ((SUM(CTE_3.vote_mean)/COUNT(CTE_3.IdProduct))) AS WeightedRating
FROM CTE_3
GROUP BY CTE_3.IdProduct,
         CTE_3.vote_count,
         CTE_3.vote_mean     
ORDER BY idProduct;
```

But the problem I am facing is that the result is ALWAYS 0.. I tried using Convert(FLOAT,operation) AS WeightedRating but still I am getting a result of 0.

When I manually perform this on a calculator it returns 2.5416666..so I am quite sure that SQL Server is not being able to manage the values I feed to the operation.

Should I do something else than cast?

The values are :
vote_count is 2 
vote_mean is 2.5
@minimumVotesRequired is 1

**EDIT :**

Now the only value after casting everything to float is 2.5 from CTE_3.vote_mean

```
SELECT CTE_3.idProduct,(CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_3.vote_count) / (CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_3.vote_count) + @minimumVotesRequired))
                        * CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_3.vote_mean) + 
                        (@minimumVotesRequired / (CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_3.vote_count)+ @minimumVotesRequired))
                        * (SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_3.vote_mean)))/COUNT(CTE_3.IdProduct)) AS WeightedRating
FROM CTE_3
GROUP BY CTE_3.IdProduct,
         CTE_3.vote_count,
         CTE_3.vote_mean     
ORDER BY idProduct;
```

Any suggestion in what am I missing?

Comment: What are the data types of the various component columns?  Is vote_count an integer [or long or similar]?

Comment: I just edited my code, apparently using COUNT breaks my code.. placing a 2 or a 3 in place of COUNT throws an appropiate value how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

If CTE_3.vote_count type is int or @minimumVotesRequired type is int, then you are getting the truncated int value.  Make sure those are floats, or cast them as floats before doing your division.

Also, don't forget that COUNT is an integer function.  You will want to cast the result of your COUNT as a float as well.

Comment: I did this but only got one value not to be truncated

Comment: If you make sure that every reference to an int is cast as a float before performing an arithmetic operation on it, you should't be seeing this problem.  Can you edit your question to include the latest version of your code?

Comment: I just edited my code, apparently using COUNT breaks my code.. placing a 2 or a 3 in place of COUNT throws an appropiate value, how can I fix this?

Comment: That's because COUNT is a function that returns an INT.  You need to cast that also.     CONVERT(float,COUNT(....))

Comment: Also, a short cut I will use is to multiple by 1.00.  That will force the int expression to result in a float through implicit casting.

Comment: Using CONVERT(FLOAT,COUNT(CTE_3.IdProduct) has the same result

Comment: What about @minimumVotesRequired?  Have your wrapped that in a cast to float, or changed it's type to float?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you remove the last piece that starts with " * (SUM(....))"  does it still get truncated?

Comment: The value does not get truncated if I remove the piece that starts with *SUM...Should I do a select inside the select to get the COUNT value?

Comment: Do you still just have "COUNT(CTE_3.IdProduct)" in the "SUM" part or did you wrap that in a cast?  Could you try wrapping "SUM" in a cast?  (That shouldn't be necessary since you are summing floats, but it would't hurt).

Comment: I did use a convert in front of SUM and CONVERT now but the values are still getting truncated                                             (CONVERT(FLOAT,(SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_3.vote_mean))))/((CONVERT(FLOAT,COUNT((CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_3.IdProduct)))))))